# Find original cost based on fractional purchase

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, percentages

How would I go about finding the original cost of bitcoin knowing that $20 purchased .0531401 of bitcoin?  I would like to know what the cost of 1 bitcoin was at the time of purchase?

```
20 / X = .0531401
```

Answer (score 1):

Let BTC be the amount you want, that is the price of one BitCoin.

If
$$ 0.0531401\cdot BTC = $20$$
Then

$$BTC = \frac{$20}{0.0531401} = $376.36 $$